# how can attach two images in mail composer

Tags: iphone, email, ios5

I am making an iPhone project for inserting two images in mail. The images are selected from the photo library and they're stored in two separate image views. When I attach the images in email, it doesn't attach it correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a html page code and insert that image as  tag and pass the whole html as string in the MFMailComposer for Body.It will look cool.
you need write this line

```
MFMailComposeViewController* controller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        controller.mailComposeDelegate = self;
        if ([recipentArray count]>0) 
        {
            [controller setToRecipients:self.recipentArray];
        }
        [controller setSubject:self.emailSubject];
        [controller setMessageBody:self.messageBody isHTML:YES]; // isHTML -> YES/NO depending the message body
        [object presentModalViewController:controller   animated:YES];
        RELEASE_SAFELY(controller);
```

Once you will implement the **MFMailComposer** you need to set **bool** if you are using html page in body.Let me know if you have any doubt.