# Unable to send email through my app

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, email, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am new to iphone development. I am building an app through which i can send the email.I am using the following code

```
- (IBAction)btnsendPressAction:(id)sender {

    if([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]){

        MFMailComposeViewController *mailer=[[MFMailComposeViewController alloc]init];
        mailer.mailComposeDelegate=self;
        [mailer setSubject:@"A Message for testing"];
      NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"rajshetty2125@gmail.com", @"secondMail@example.com", nil];
        [mailer setToRecipients:toRecipients];

        UIImage *image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"];
        NSData *imageData=UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
        [mailer addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/png" fileName:@"logo.png"];
        NSString *emailBody=@"This is test email";
        [mailer setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [self presentModalViewController:mailer animated:YES];
        mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet ;


    }
    else{

        UIAlertView *alert=[[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"failure" message:@"Alert" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
    }
}
```

My problem is mailComposeController delegate is not getting called and I am not able to send email through my app.I went through many links , but every where I found the same method. Can anyone help me on this ?

Comment: I have also added the proper method for the delegate in my code , which I have not put here.

Comment: Check if the mail id is configured in your device you using.

Comment: I am testing it my simulator and may I know how to configure ?

Comment: Okay,you wont be able to mail through simulator and to configure in device : http://support.apple.com/kb/ht4810

Comment: That means I wont be able to test it in simulator ??

Comment: No,check out the answers provided to you,it will sure help you. :)

Comment: But he have a problem that his delegate is not getting called? You can't send email but you can test it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You won't be able to send email from Simulator. You can only check this functionality on iOS device with any account configured in Mail application.

Comment: Ok I will check it real device once and will get back to you

Comment: yea ok . I may take some time to test it on device , coz as of now I am not having a device

Comment: It worked properly in device but the image which I wanted to attach didn't get attached

Comment: In the simulator, I will be able to send the mail , but the actual mail doesn't get sent to the recipient mail address.That is every thing appears normal, only the thing is mail won't be delivered

Answer (score 0):

Here use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12000698/how-can-attach-two-images-in-mail-composer/12001392#12001392) and your add(configured) an account in device then only you can send the mail.

Comment: And that will allow the the delegate to be called will it?

Comment: you can use that code,it's working for me.You need to set the delegate and same time conform that MFMailComposerDelegate.i got one down Please tell me what's wrong in that??

Answer (score 0):

This snippet is working for me:

```
if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {
    self.mailController = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [self.mailController setSubject:@"Invitation"];
    [self.mailController setMessageBody:@"Message" isHTML:NO];
    self.mailController.mailComposeDelegate = self;

    [self presentModalViewController:self.mailController animated:YES];
}
```

but make sure that you're implement delegate in interface

```
@interface MyClass() <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

and check your callback method:

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error
{
}
```

Comment: Yes it work on simulator, my delegate is called but you will not recive email on your e-mail account, try to make property of your MFMailComposeViewController, maybe ARC is dealocating your mailViewController befor they send delegate or sth. You don't need a recipient address in code, you can choose it from address book or enter manually.

Answer (score -1):

hey i am not sure but may be it's helpful, replace your last line

```
mailer.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPageSheet ;
```

with

```
[self presentModalViewController: mailer animated:YES];
```

Comment: I have personally test in my app when i check the code with first line it's not present the mail view. when i try with my second line it's shoe action sheet and i can even send mail. so it's not be downvoted answer